# Async procedure call using service broker in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, message-queue, service-broker, loose-coupling

I have a backup procedure (production) running daily on a schedule and the backups generated are used periodically to refresh the lower environments. I'm building an automated solution to download .bak files to lower environments (different server). I'm reluctant to use **MIRROR TO**  option in backup as it may effect the normal backup operation if something fails in mirror to . I here want to use service broker and asynchronously trigger file copy from prod to lower environment at the end of the backup procedure. I've had put lot of effort in understanding service broker , message type, service , queue and contract. Everything's fine until here. Now I just want to understand on how to trigger filecopy procedure with some custom logic at the end of backup using service broker. I've played around with the following script to understand service broker. Someone kindly guide me on how to build a solution out of this.

```
------------------------------------------------------------SETUP--------------------------------------------

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//SBTest/SBSample/RequestMessage] VALIDATION=WELL_FORMED_XML;

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//SBTest/SBSample/ReplyMessage] VALIDATION=WELL_FORMED_XML; 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE CONTRACT [//SBTest/SBSample/SBContract]
(
[//SBTest/SBSample/RequestMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR ,
[//SBTest/SBSample/ReplyMessage] SENT BY TARGET 
);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE QUEUE SBInitiatorQueue; 

CREATE QUEUE SBTargetQueue; 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE SERVICE [//SBTest/SBSample/SBInitiatorService] ON QUEUE SBInitiatorQueue; 

CREATE SERVICE [//SBTest/SBSample/SBTargetService] ON QUEUE SBTargetQueue ([//SBTest/SBSample/SBContract]); 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------





-------------------------------------------------------INITIATE QUE-----------------------------------------
DECLARE @InitDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @RequestMessage VARCHAR(1000) 

BEGIN TRAN 

--Determine the Initiator Service, Target Service and the Contract 

BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
FROM SERVICE [//SBTest/SBSample/SBInitiatorService] TO SERVICE'//SBTest/SBSample/SBTargetService'
ON CONTRACT
[//SBTest/SBSample/SBContract]
WITH ENCRYPTION=OFF; 


--Prepare the Message
SELECT @RequestMessage = N'HAHA'; 


--Send the Message
SEND ON CONVERSATION @InitDlgHandle 
MESSAGE TYPE
[//SBTest/SBSample/RequestMessage]
(@RequestMessage);

SELECT @RequestMessage AS SentRequestMessage;

COMMIT TRAN 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------






-------------------------------------------------------READ QUE-------------------------------------------------

\DECLARE @TargetDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @ReplyMessage VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @ReplyMessageName Sysname 

BEGIN TRAN; 

--Receive message from Initiator
RECEIVE TOP(1)
@TargetDlgHandle=Conversation_Handle, @ReplyMessage=Message_Body, @ReplyMessageName=Message_Type_Name
 FROM SBTargetQueue; 

SELECT @ReplyMessage AS ReceivedRequestMessage; 

-- Confirm and Send a reply
IF @ReplyMessageName=N'HAHA'

BEGIN
DECLARE @RplyMsg VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @RplyMsg =N'HI'; 

SEND ON CONVERSATION @TargetDlgHandle
MESSAGE TYPE
[//SBTest/SBSample/ReplyMessage]
(@RplyMsg);
END CONVERSATION @TargetDlgHandle;

END 

SELECT @RplyMsg AS SentReplyMessage; 

COMMIT TRAN;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Triggering occurs using "Internal Activation". You need to create a stored procedure that will be triggered when a message enters the queue, reads from the queue, then does the work. 
Adapted from the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281526(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TargetActivProc
AS
  DECLARE @RecvReqDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
  DECLARE @RecvReqMsg NVARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE @RecvReqMsgName sysname;

  WHILE (1=1)
  BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WAITFOR
    ( RECEIVE TOP(1)
        @RecvReqDlgHandle = conversation_handle,
        @RecvReqMsg = message_body,
        @RecvReqMsgName = message_type_name
      FROM TargetQueueIntAct
    ), TIMEOUT 5000;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      BREAK;
    END

    IF @RecvReqMsgName =
       N'//SBTest/SBSample/RequestMessage'
    BEGIN

      --do work here
    END
    ELSE IF @RecvReqMsgName =
        N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog'
    BEGIN
       END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
    END
    ELSE IF @RecvReqMsgName =
        N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
    BEGIN
       END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

  END
GO
```

The next part is to enable activation on the queue

```
ALTER QUEUE SBTargetQueue
    WITH ACTIVATION
    ( STATUS = ON,
      PROCEDURE_NAME = TargetActivProc,
      MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
      EXECUTE AS SELF
    );
```

The procedure will be activated when a message arrives in the queue and will remain activated and looping until the queue is empty.

Comment: Richard Cupples

For a while if the queue goes empty, what triggers it again ? The new message in the queue triggers it?

Comment: @TharunRaja That's correct. So long as there is a message in the queue SQL Server will periodically check if the number of activated processes is < MAX_QUEUE_READERS and will then start a new one. Each of these processes will terminate when they return zero rows from the queue.

Comment: I've tried alter queue script and had attached some random procedure name to it which does inserts into a dummy table. Sometimes I see procedure attached to the queue getting executed when there is a message in a queue and sometimes I don't see it getting executed. What's with MAX_QUEUE_READERS option and the number of messages in a queue? Your answers helped me a lot in understanding service broker. Thank You.

Comment: MAX_QUEUE_READERS is the maximum number of reader processes that SQL server will activate simultaneously and is defined per queue.

Comment: As I asked , sometimes the procedure attached to the target_queue is getting triggered and sometimes not even when the queue has a new message incoming. What could be the reason for it? Also is it possible to attach two different procedures to the queue. Just curious to trigger two different procedures simultaneously with service broker.

Comment: I can't say why it's not always being triggered, maybe it's producing an error? Check the server log. There are also some dmvs for monitoring the Service Broker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/service-broker-related-dynamic-management-views-transact-sql
It's not possible to attach 2 different procedures - for this you would have to implement some sort of routing - The activated procedure calls another procedure depending on the contents of the message